# Get all items except max value from each group - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Due to some bug, we have got duplicate user entries in our table, I want to create a temp table with all rows except the latest record

```
id  name  unique_id  created_at 
-----------------------------------------
1   aaaa  1          2018-01-20 13:40:30
2   aaaa  1          2017-01-20 13:40:30
3   aaaa  1          2016-01-20 13:40:30
4   bbbb  2          2018-01-20 13:40:30
5   bbbb  2          2017-01-20 13:40:30
6   bbbb  2          2016-01-20 13:40:30
7   cccc  3          2018-01-20 13:40:30
8   cccc  3          2017-01-20 13:40:30
9   cccc  3          2016-01-20 13:40:30
```

what would be the query to get the following result, so that I can store it in another table

```
id  name  unique_id  created_at
----------------------------------------
2   aaaa  1          2017-01-20 13:40:30
3   aaaa  1          2016-01-20 13:40:30
5   bbbb  2          2017-01-20 13:40:30
6   bbbb  2          2016-01-20 13:40:30
8   cccc  3          2017-01-20 13:40:30
9   cccc  3          2016-01-20 13:40:30
```

Answer (score 0):

`DELETE FROM user WHERE id IN (SELECT id, MAX(created_at) from user GROUP BY unique_id)`

Comment: thanks, but I just want the exact reverse of this ^ , I don't want to delete them in one shot, need to log them in another table.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be asking for:

```
create temporary table t as 
    select u.*
    from users u
    where u.id < (select max(u2.id) from users u2 where u2.unique_id = u.unique_id);
```

If performance is an issue, you want an index on `users(unique_id, id)`.

Comment: I want to get ids' from inner query based on created_at field; corresponding id which has got  latest created_at from each group.

Answer (score 0):

Since I had millions of records, I did something like this, using 3 temp tables

-- get all max value in individual group

```
create temporary table max_value_table as select id,unique_id from users c inner join (select max(created_at)as date1, unique_id as pi from users group by unique_id having count(*) > 1) d on c.created_at = d.date1;
```

-- join with original(users) table get only duplicate records (to ignore the ids' of single occurrence)

```
create temporary table duplicate_value_table  as select c.id,name,c.unique_id,c.created_at from users c inner join max_value_table t on c.unique_id = t.unique_id;
```

-- join duplicate_value_table table with tamp and store it in result_table

```
create temporary table result_table as select t2.id,name,t2.unique_id,t2.created_at from duplicate_value_table t2 inner join max_value_table t1 on t1.unique_id = t2.unique_id and t2.id != t1.id;
```

now, result_table has all values which can be deleted later.